# Graph Polar equation: $r = \sin^2(\theta)$ in polar plane

Tags: polar-coordinates

[image]

That's the answer, but I don't understand how to get there. Especially how to draw it. I tried looking it up but I am unable to find resources on graphing on polar plane.

Also, how am I supposed to convert $r = \sin^2(\theta)$ to cartesian?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Take $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ as a parameter.  Then $x = r\cos\theta = \sin^2\theta\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta = \sin^3\theta$.  You can plot the parametric curve or go on to obtain an implicit equation involving only $x$ and $y$ if you can eliminate $\theta$ from these two equations.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=r\cos\theta=\sin^2\theta\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta=\sin^3\theta$$
From the second equation $$\sin\theta=\sqrt[3]y$$
You can then plug it into the first equation, and use $\cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$:
$$x=\pm y^\frac23\sqrt{1-y^\frac23}$$
Notice that you plot $x(y)$.

Comment: I don't follow, first $x = \sin^2(\theta)cos(theta)$ where did that come from and the following y = $\sin^3(\theta)$, and how do we transform $r = \sin^2(\theta)$ into x = etc. I honestly don't see and understand.

Comment: How do you transform from polar to Cartesian coordinates? In the $x-y$ plane, draw a line from origin to a point at a distance $r$, where the line makes an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. Project the line on the two axes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates Then use $r=\sin^2\theta$